# Project Hamster Time Traker, lack of Unity support

Tags: 11.04, unity, indicator, time-management

I used to use the hamster time tracker. 
It is a wonderful application, easy to use and simple. However, with the move to Unity, it does not work properly due to the lack of integration. Are there any plans to integrate this tool to Unity ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hamster is used by many people, but I know personally only 1-2 people who use it.

Alberto Milone has [come up with a AppIndictaor](http://albertomilone.com/wordpress/?p=502) for Hamster

Also you can check this from [Project Hamster blog](http://www.janhouse.lv/blog/linux/hamster-time-tracker-in-system-tray/)

Answer (score 8):

From Ubuntu 12.04 there is an Application Indicator for the hamster tracker available in the repositories.

[image: Install via the software center]