# Time Tracker - How to use in Unity (Precise)

Tags: unity, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Project Hamster Time Traker, lack of Unity support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35906/project-hamster-time-traker-lack-of-unity-support)

Firstly (unrelated), I been using Ubuntu Forums for like forever and first time using this site...absolutely awesome +1.

Anyway,
Back in university I lived by Hamster Tracking, this was such a great tool and since I had to prove how long I spent on projects, it was amazing for that use.

The problem I now have is that Tracking Tool is still in the Precise repos, but unlike it's older pre-unity version, it no longer comes up in the taskbar.
Is there any hack I can use to add it there?